# Disable Stock / Index Selection in tradingview

Tags: charts, trading, tradingview-api

[image]

I want to disable the stock selection in tradingview.

Answer (score 1):

Use **header_symbol_search** if disabled_features:

```
    disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"
                        , "header_symbol_search"
    ],
```